# Selenium throws StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Testing CEF-based one-page application and have some problems. So, my application can generate an output file in many different configurations that are available to choose from dependent on each other dropdown lists.

Trying to generate files for all possible options by simulating the appropriate clicking: display list select the first possible option -> the same with list2 -> the same with list3 again -> go forward -> export file -> go back to the beginning.

```
        for (WebElement material : materialList) {
        displayMaterialList.click();
        material.click();
        for (WebElement size : sizeList) {
            displaySizeList.click();
            size.click();
            for (WebElement thickness : thicknessList) {
                displayThicknessList.click();
                thickness.click();
                //Exporting file:
                nextStepButton.click()
                nextStepButton.click();
                exportFileButton.click();
                copyPasteText("filename" + "_" + currentDataTime);
                previousStepButton.click();;
            }
        }
    }
```

These loops work fine without exporting file fragment embedded in the deepest loop, used them to display combinations of all possible options. But when I added file naming and exporting fragment tests project threw out
`StaleElementReferenceException` just after generated file, at the start of the second iteration. I think it can't find `thickness.click();` but don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

according to [Exception Doc Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/exceptions/)

Common Causes

A stale element reference exception is thrown in one of two cases, the first being more common than the second:

```
The element has been deleted entirely.
The element is no longer attached to the DOM.
```

Please check that, and if can't see the html tha you are trying to test in pretty difficult give a appropiate answer.

Comment: One of WebElements, specifically thickness was being created by every single iteration. I had to embedd finding it inside loop, instead of using @FindBy annotation.